# Accessing Laravel through LAN and can't redirect to '/' after login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, lan

I have installed laravel on another machine and I'm trying to login to Laravel through LAN via my web browser using ipaddress/laravel/public. I am able to view the login page but when I try to login I get this message

> This page isn’t working
>
> 192.168.1.17 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

What step did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check on your local host if it works correctly

Comment: Check your server logs, Error 500 means "Internal error"; something gone wrong in the server.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, something was indeed missing on it. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I strongly recommend you to elaborate on what was missing. Otherwise, this answer is not really useful for future readers of this post. Thank you.